# Embedding sender's signature in document using Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

Using Docusign API i am uploading the document with text tag for signature. I need to prefill the sender's signature in the document before sending it to the recipient. How can i achieve this with API's? Suggest me if there is any alternatives.
Is it possible to sign a document as part of sending in DocuSign API?

Answer (score 0):

By "prefill the sender's signature" you mean sign on behalf of the sender?

The DocuSign cloud eSignature service does not enable you to programmatically sign a document on behalf of a person.

A workaround is to photocopy / scan the the sender's signature on to the original PDF.

A standard signing / counter-signing flow is for the sender to send the unsigned document to the customer for signature, the customer signs, then the sender counter-signs.